# Stop TimerTask inside Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, timer

I have stuck and don't know how to stop 2 Timer in my program. I have one Thread which is initialize the connection with a socket, then I have two Runnables which one is for the InputStream and one for OutputStream Here is my code:

```
public class Receiver extends Thread {
public void run() {

        initializeThreads();

    }

public static void initializeThreads() {

        try {

            // create new thread pool with four threads
            application = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            // create ArrayBlockQueueSync to store ints
            Buffer sharedLocation = new ArrayBlockQueueSync();
            // execute tasks
            application.submit(new Reader(client.getInputStream(), sharedLocation));
            application.submit(new Writer(client.getOutputStream(), sharedLocation));
            application.submit(new MyTimer1(sharedLocation));
            application.submit(new MyTimer2(sharedLocation));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            WriteExceptions.writeToFile(e);
            System.err.println("Error on the run Receiver.\n" + e);
        }

    }

    public static void disconnect() {
        try {
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Close Socket");
            shutdownAndAwaitTermination();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            WriteExceptions.writeToFile(e);
        }
    }
    // This I found on the javadoc
    public static void shutdownAndAwaitTermination() {
        application.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if (!application.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                application.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if (!application.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            WriteExceptions.writeToFile(ie);
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            application.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

The Writer and Reader is like the follow:

```
public class Writer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                // read or write the socket
            }

        }
}
```

And the Timers like this:

```
public class Timer1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Declare the timer
            Timer t = new Timer();
            // Set the schedule function and rate
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // perform my task
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        WriteExceptions.writeToFile(e);
                    }
                }

            },5 * 60 * 1000,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            WriteExceptions.writeToFile(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem, the timer is not stop, when I call the disconnect method of the Receiver.Thanks

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `TimerTask`s, for starters; and don't extend `Thread`.

Comment: Note that `Executors` can also provide instances of `ScheduledExecutorService`s

Comment: I will have problem If do it like this:
application = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   // create ArrayBlockQueueSync to store ints
   Buffer sharedLocation = new ArrayBlockQueueSync();
   // execute tasks
   Future<?> t1 = application.submit(new Reader(client.getInputStream(), sharedLocation));
   Future<?> t2 = application.submit(new Writer(client.getOutputStream(), sharedLocation));
    
   sd = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
   
   Future<?> t3 = sd.submit(new Timer1(sharedLocation));
   Future<?> t4 = sd.submit(new Timer2(sharedLocation));

Comment: As I said: ask `Executors` to provide you with a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead; it extends `ExecutorService`, which means everything you can do with the latter you can do with the former as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @fge suggestion, I use ScheduledExecutorService class and work fine.